# NHibernate session management in RESTful API with Tasks/Threads

Tags: c#, asp.net, multithreading, api, nhibernate

I'm building a set of APIs. One of them is a authentication API, that returns JWT tokens. I'm trying to implement a Session per Action approach, with `ActionFiltersAttribute`. My controller is decorated with this attribute:

```
public class NHibernateSessionAttribute : ActionFilterAttribute
    {
        public override void OnActionExecuting(HttpActionContext actionContext)
        {
            var session = NHibernateSessionManager.SessionFactory.OpenSession();
            session.BeginTransaction();            
            CurrentSessionContext.Bind(session);
        }

        public override void OnActionExecuted(HttpActionExecutedContext actionExecutedContext)
        {
            var session = CurrentSessionContext.Unbind(NHibernateSessionManager.SessionFactory)            
            if (session != null)
            {
                if (session.Transaction.IsActive)
                {
                    try
                    {
                        session.Transaction.Commit();
                    }
                    catch
                    {
                        session.Transaction.Rollback();
                    }
                }

                session.Close();
            }
        }
    }
```

Where is the problem? To manage the users with NHibernate istead of Entity Framework I've implemented all the needed ASP.NET Identity interfaces, and they all return a `Task<T>`. For example on the following action:

```
AccountController.cs

public async Task<IHttpActionResult> ChangePassword(ChangePasswordBindingModel model)
        {
            if (!ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                return BadRequest(ModelState);
            }

            IdentityResult result = await UserManager.ChangePasswordAsync(User.Identity.GetUserId(), model.OldPassword,
                model.NewPassword);

            if (!result.Succeeded)
            {
                return GetErrorResult(result);
            }

            return Ok();
        }
```

There `ChangePasswordAsync` calls internally several methods wich have code inside new tasks, where the `SessionFactory.GetCurrentSession()` causes a `NullException`. As far as I know, because that's another Thread and context.
In code, the first attempt to save executes with no fail, and the second not. The duplicated code is only to ilustrate the situation.

```
UserStore.cs

public System.Threading.Tasks.Task UpdateAsync(UserModel user)
    {
        if (user == null)
        {
            throw new ArgumentNullException("user");
        }
        //Here the Session is found
        DataProviderI<UserModel, int> prov = new DataProviderImplGeneric<UserModel, int>();
        prov.Save(user);


        return Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
        {
            //Here the Session is NOT found
            DataProviderI<UserModel, int> prov2 = new DataProviderImplGeneric<UserModel, int>();
            prov.Save(user);
        });
    }
```

What's the best way to deal with this and get the same `ISession` during all the `Action` ?

As far as I know NHibernate doesn't support async calls and I could refactorize the methods with a return of type `Task.FromResult(0)` on void cases or `Task.FromResult<T>(T)` where T is an object, but I would like to know if there's another solution to take advantage of parallelism

Comment: Have a look at using a DI library, [simpleinjector](https://simpleinjector.org/index.html) is as good as any. Using a DI container you can tie the lifetime of an instance to a scope, in your case you want to tie an `ISession` to a web request. SimpleInjector is great for this and works well with Tasks and async.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems like the problem you are dealing with is stemming from the HttpContext being null while inside a task and therefore cannot access the NHibernate session stored inside of the context variable.

You could work around this by getting the ISession before you call into a task.

Add in a constructor to your DataProviderImplGeneric so you manually pass one in.

```
DataProviderImplGeneric(ISession session) {
      this.session = session;
}
```

just retrieve the session before you call into this from inside a task.

```
var session = GetCurrentNHibernateSession();

return Task.Factory.StartNew(() => {
    var dataProvider = DataProviderImplGeneric<UserModel, int>(session);
    return dataProvider.Save(user);
}
```